# X509Extension format is taking too long to execute

Tags: c#, digital-certificate, x509certificate2

I use X509Extension class in a Brazilian Invoicing system so I can read specific data from the X509Certificate2 and use it to execute some functionalities.

But in some PCs I'm getting a huge delay (2+ minutes) when I execute *extension.Format(true)* method, without any reason at all.

Things I already looked into:

- Cleaned temporary files
- Cleaned SSl cache in Internet Explorer
- Reinstalled the certificate
- Renamed %APPDATA%/Microsoft/Protect/*ID* folder so the system would create a new one
- Used Process Hacker to check if there was any writing that could take too long (there wasn't)

Here's the code I use to obtain the data.
Is there anything else I could do? Could there be any reason (even in the certificate itself) that could lead to this delay?

```
public static class X509Certificate2Extensions
{
    public static String ObterInformacaoDasExtensoes(this X509Certificate2 certificado,
        String chaveExtensao)
    {
        String retorno = String.Empty;
        foreach (X509Extension extension in certificado.Extensions)
        {
            String format = extension.Format(true); // <--- The delay is here
            String[] linhas = format.Split(new[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (String linha in linhas)
            {
                if (!linha.Trim().StartsWith(chaveExtensao))
                    continue;

                String valorLinha = linha.Substring(linha.IndexOf('=') + 1);                    
                String[] sequencia = valorLinha.Split(' ');
                Int32 tamanho = sequencia.Length - 2;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[tamanho];

                for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
                    bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(sequencia[i + 2], 16);

                retorno = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);                    
                break;
            }
        }

        return retorno;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am also from Brazil and I was with the same problem as you, the solution to my case was the domain where the machine was inserted. Removing the machine and reinserting everything returned to normal operation.

The problem was exactly the same, so I think it might work for you too.